# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid') at getExpenses (index.js:76:1) at index.js:11:1

Tags: javascript, react, firebase

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo com reactJs que faz uma lista de despesas a pagar, e utilizo o firebase firestore como banco de dados e autenticação do google. Na página onde as despesas são carregadas usei useEffect para pesquisar e carregá-las, mas assim que entro estou encontrando o erro abaixo, mas se eu recarregar a página assim que recarregar a página o erro desaparece e tudo funciona normalmente:

```
index.js:76 
 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')
    at getExpenses (index.js:76:1)
    at index.js:11:1
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:22969:1)
    at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24702:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24666:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24653:1)
    at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24641:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:26848:1)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:26801:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:26597:1
```

Uso este estado para armazenar os dados de usuário do authgoogle firebase:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
```

Função de login:

```
const signIn = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
      .then((result) => {
        const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
        const token = credential.accessToken;
        const user = result.user;
        setUser(user);
        sessionStorage.setItem("@AuthFirebase:token", token);
        sessionStorage.setItem("@AuthFirebase:user", JSON.stringify(user));
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Aqui eu converto os dados vindos do firestore para um objeto.

```
let userOn = null;

try {
    userOn = JSON.parse(user);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
```

Função que pega os dados:

```
const getExpenses = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await getDocs(collection(db, userOn.uid));
      setExpenses(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(userOn.uid);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Parece que o problema é que esse `getExpenses` tem uma dependência com o `userOn` e em algum momento ele ta `null`, talvez seja no primeiro render quando o firestore, não sei, não tem o código completo.

Eu sugiro você colocar a chamada desse `getExpenses` dentro de um `useEffect` com o `userOn` como dependencia ou algo parecido, dependendo do resto do código.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (userOn) {
    getExpenses()
  }
},[userOn])
```